# Tell Conky to update from a separate process

Tags: conky

I have Conky display my current volume with `${exec bash /path/to/script/getvolume.sh}`. However I have noticed that after changing the volume, I have to wait a while for Conky to update. Is it possible for me to write another script `changevolume.sh`, so that `./changevolume.sh 12` would not only change the volume but also make Conky update itself immediately afterwards so that I don't have to wait for the usual update interval period?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use command line to change volume?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21089/how-to-use-command-line-to-change-volume)

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, I know. But it's what your question boils down to.

Comment: @JosephR. It is related but i'm not sure that's what it boils down to. Changing the volume is easy, but after changing it, I have to wait a few seconds for the results to be updated on Conky. What I want is a way for Conky to display the correct volume immediately after the volume has changed

Comment: You're right. My bad. I wasn't paying attention. Close vote retracted.

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know, there is no way of externally forcing `conky` to update short of killing and restarting it. The good news is that you don't need to, you can just set `conky` to update more often using the `update_interval` setting:

```
update_interval 1
```

This is a configuration option, so it has to be placed in the header of your `.conkyrc`, before the `TEXT` block.

Bear in mind that the lower the interval, the higher `conky`'s CPU usage since it will be running more often. It is up to you to decide if it is worth it.

The only other option would be to have your `getvolume.sh` script kill and restart `conky`. Add this line to the end of your script:

```
killall conky; conky &
```

@Joseph R found this in `conky`'s man page:

```
   An easy way to force Conky to reload your ~/.conkyrc: "killall -SIGUSR1
   conky". Saves you the trouble of having to kill and then  restart.  You
   can now also do the same with SIGHUP.
```

So you could force `conky` to reread its init file by adding this command to the end of your `getvolume.sh`:

```
killall -SIGUSR1 conky
```

Comment: The `execi` interval can't be lower than the update interval (see the man page). FWIW, no need to restart `conky`, if you send it `SIGUSR1` or `SIGHUP` it will reload its rc file (again see man page). I had posted this as an answer but deleted it because its effect will be disconcerting to the OP and is definitely not what he/she is looking for.

Comment: @JosephR. I never suggested the execi interval be shorter than the update one. They are just two different ways of getting the desired behavior. And yes, I saw your answer (it's still visible to >10k users) but thought it was actually killing and restarting, just checked and saw that it doesn't. Should I add this to mine, or will you undelete your answer? Conky almost certainly forks for `exec` calls but the `killall` call causes it to rerun them so your answer seems fine to me.

Comment: Feel free to add my answer's content to yours. I still don't believe it's what the OP is looking for.

Comment: @JosephR. agreed but I'm pretty sure it's the best he'll get :).

Comment: I'm more inclined to think that your first solution (lowering the update interval) is much better if the higher CPU usage is tolerable.

Comment: @JosephR. the best would be `execi`, that way only one command needs to be run every second, not everything in the `conkyrc`. Mind you, my own `conky` updates every second and I have no issues with it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11003/discussion-between-joseph-r-and-terdon)

Comment: Looking at the source code, conky decides to update if `select` returns -1. You could ptrace it and hook around the `select` syscall to return -1 when desired… It would be as much work as adding the feature to update upon receipt of a signal.

Comment: Worth noting - reloading the init file does _not_ re-execute `texeci` blocks with a long interval.